# Source code for java.lang.Object

Tags: java

Is there any web site that I could see the source code for the Java standard library? Most so the two classes java.lang.* and java.net.* ??

Comment: Of course, the vast majority of `Object` is `native` functions not in the *Java* source code (but rather the C code of the JVM)...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026093/is-jvm-open-source-code-if-not-how-can-i-get-code-of-jvm

Answer (score 4):

Please install Java JDK (Java Developer Kit), which is not the same as Java JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

The Java JDK contains the Java source code.

And you'd better to use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) such as Eclipse or NetBeans to develop Java programs.

You can look for the java code via the IDE tool.

Comment: I have the java JDK installed I just do not know how to view the code inside of it

Comment: If you install an eclipse, the eclipse IDE will help you to find the java source code automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. You could find it in the JDK, but also online. I also use the online version, because I find it faster as to open the folder with the JDK, brows through all the files and so on. Just google "java source object".

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html

Comment: I'd recommend [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java), it's the sh*t these days. Hyperlinked code, find derived items, find usages, highlight all occurrences in file, ...

Comment: @Marko Topolnik nice site! It is even with FindBugs annotations!

Comment: @StephenC that's just a colloquialism, but I guess the standards here frown even upon that.

Comment: I went on the site, I only see code for java.lang. I do not see the java.net package of the library.

Answer (score 1):

You need the JDK (JAVA SDK) installed and source of class library is at (on Windows):

```
C:\<Program Files>\Java\<JDK>\src.zip
```

Like

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\src.zip
```

Comment: I think `src.zip` should be in the JDK folder in MAC as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java source code is available in JDK distribution. If you have installed JDK on your machine, in JDK directory you'll find **src.zip**. For example, in my windows machine source code is available at: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12**.

Alternatively, you can find Java source code online at: [Java Source Code](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/)

Thanks,
Mrityunjoy