# Where can I view the API which the JVM calls for thread manipulation?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I'd like to take a deeper look into Java and the JVM and I guess I need to access the C/C++ code the JVM is written in, can anyone recommend the best way of doing this, which JVM to look at and what I'd need to get started.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026093/is-jvm-open-source-code

Comment: The JVM doesn't implement threads, it gets the underling threading library and the OS to do all the real work.