# Java implementation in C (maybe platform-specific)

Tags: java, c, oop, implementation, object-model

I've had a look at Ruby's implementation in C to learn more about it's object model and the way it implements object-oriented programming. I'd like to find something similar for Java. I understand that Java works very differently with the translation to bytecodes, the JVM and all the stuff.

Is there a source code (maybe in C) from which I can learn OOP concepts in Java (maybe for a particular implementation)? (I'm very interested for instance in how that implementation manages inheritance which is not specified by the standard)

Comment: You want the source for the compiler? The JVM?

Comment: Really compiler source ?

Comment: Both would be useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JVM open source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026093/is-jvm-open-source-code)

Comment: According to this post https://community.oracle.com/message/6460990#6460990 the only part of the JVM that is written in c++ is the BootStrap Class Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have  look at OpenJDK for a start (http://openjdk.java.net/) and its source code at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/