# If java is open source then why source code of JVM is not provided to us?

Tags: java, jvm, open-source

The oracle community says that Java is open source then why the source code of the JVM is not provided along with JDK. The class that are provided inside src.zip are more of libraries required to run the Java Program.

Comment: Why would you need the JVM source code to use the JDK?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2026360/3904086).

Comment: Go [nuts](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/).

Comment: The source is much bigger than the release so adding all the source would make it much bigger to download and install, however you rarely need to see the original other than what is provided in src.zip.

Comment: Many open source projects make downloading the source for that program/library optional.